# How to use APScheduler without installing it?

Tags: apscheduler

I know the normal way to use APScheduler is "python setup.py install". But I want to embed it into my program directly, so the user don't need install it when using my program.

```
class BaseScheduler(six.with_metaclass(ABCMeta)):

_trigger_plugins = dict((ep.name, ep) for ep in iter_entry_points('apscheduler.triggers'))
# print(_trigger_plugins, 'ddd')
_trigger_classes = {}
_executor_plugins = dict((ep.name, ep) for ep in iter_entry_points('apscheduler.executors'))
_executor_classes = {}
_jobstore_plugins = dict((ep.name, ep) for ep in iter_entry_points('apscheduler.jobstores'))
_jobstore_classes = {}
_stopped = True
```

thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to work around this problem.

1. use 'pip install apscheduler' to install locally
2. goto the installed directory and cp that directory to your lib directory
3. use 'pip uninstall apscheduler' to remove it.
4. make you code to import the apscheduler from your lib directory.
5. done.

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate the triggers directly, without going through their aliases. That eliminates the need to install APScheduler or setuptools. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hey Alex, do you have a link to documentation of where I can learn more about instantiating triggers directly? I am passing APscheduler through our Nexus IQ vulnerability scanner and it is flagging Setuptools 61.2.0 as a vulnerability.
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/227

Comment: The trigger classes are documented as part of the APScheduler documentation. Just pass the trigger instance directly to `add_job()`. This design has turned out to be bad in retrospect and has been changed in master (upcoming v4.0).